# Why have I only thwarted 30% of Harley's Revenge?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

So, I got Harley's Revenge this morning, and decided I'd play through it. Overall, not very long, so I ended up beating it... or so I thought. The credits rolled and so I assumed I was done. I didn't get all the balloons, nor did I

> disarm the bombs in 3 minutes

though, so I went back to go get those again. I got a few more of the balloons, got through to the part where

> I've saved the first cop and need to investigate the location they were beat up for clues

I'm taking a break so I popped back out to the main menu, and wanted to see my stats. When looking in the stats area, I saw that I had 28/30 balloons (which I already knew from the map screen) and there weren't any fun stats specifically about Harley's Revenge. But I did notice that on the stats page, it lists my story progress as 30%.

Is there more story after the credits, an alternate way of doing things, or is this just a "feature" where that counter resets every time you start a new run of the DLC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played through the Harley DLC twice an noticed this, at the time I was confused but it climbed up to 100% when I completed it the second time and then to test what I suspected was going on I restarted a 3rd time and the percentage reset again.

So I am pretty sure it displays the percentage of your current saved play through.